# Django: Protect view with HTTP Basic Auth and separate user model?

Tags: django, basic-authentication

I have a little shop-like app powered by Django (1.7), that needs to process credit cards using external gateway.

I have my own `User` table for customers. They login via form and auth data is kept within sessions.

Now, payment gateway needs to access my app's predefined urls via SSL & Basic Auth.

How I can protect this (and only this) url with HTTP Basic Auth? Also I don't want to add the gateway user in my `User` table. Also, I don't want my custommers access that secret URL with their credentials (of course, the URL is not displayed to users, but you should never trust the users, right?)

I could to that with HTTP-server (nginx/apache) settings, but then, I can't test this behavior via django test framework.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check the `request.META['REMOTE_USER']` and `request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` against your custom credentials, wherever those credentials reside. If the request isn't properly authorized, you need to send back a HTTP 401 Unauthorized response:

```
def some_view(request, **kwargs):
    if not remote_user_is_authenticated(...):    
        response = HttpResponse()
        response.status_code = 401
        response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="%s"' % realm
        return response
```

If you're using Apache with mod_wsgi, the `REMOTE_USER` Meta header won't be passed on to your application by default; you'll need to put `WSGIPassAuthorization On` in your Apache config file. Nginx probably has a similar setting (or not, I really don't know :P).